# How many times number occurs in other numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have different values of meal vouchers.

I want to enter the payout value and get exactly how many vouchers of each, the person is going to get.

Here is a picture for better understanding.

[image]

In the picture there is this example. A person gets a payout of 64€ and the result is how many of 4.2 , 4 , 3.8..... vouchers he has to get.

[Image of Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjexf.png)

Comment: So what do you see as being the answer to the above?  How is the logic supposed to work?  Do we give one of each then add one to each till the price is filled?  Do we do the maximum of the highest price then go down the list filling a maximum till the price is filled?  Not enough information.

Comment: What is 64? Can you give an example of the math regarding 64?

Comment: You have 10 variables potentially and a linear equation - not possible to solve it without more information.

Comment: 64 is someones payout like in euros  and i want to know how many of each vounchers is he going to get , i want like somne algoritm or something to count everthing for me

Comment: @Denis Demo does the total sum of vouchers have to equal 64 or the closest number less than 64?

Comment: the more close the better it will be cause 64 is only like example , someone can get his payout like 100€ so it will be 100 etc

Comment: Wouldn't the decision to select the voucher depend on the person buying the vouchers? Do you have full license to determine how many of each voucher type to select for each user?

Comment: Well i just need that thing in excel :D im living in slovakia things are different here :)

Comment: Okay no problem - but you need to give some rule. Give you a simple example. If say the total is 2 Euros - do you select 2 vouchers of 1 Euro or 1 voucher of 2 Euro.

Comment: one 2 euro vouncher :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These scenarios are very difficult to solve with formulas, but if you don't require the exact amount as the total of the vouchers, but a close approximate, then try this:

```
B4 =IF($L4>B$3,INT($L4/B$3),0)
C4 =IF($L4-SUMPRODUCT(($B4:B4)*($B$3:B$3))<C$3,0,INT(($L4-SUMPRODUCT(($B4:B4)*($B$3:B$3)))/C$3))
```

Copy C4 across and then copy B to K down.

[image]

With this approach the highest voucher value will be considered first. In some cases this may not be the best approach. There are numbers where it would be better to ignore the higher value vouchers and hand out more smaller value vouchers to get closest to the total value. For example, if the payout is $7, it would be best to give out two 3.5 vouchers. The formula will use one $4.2 voucher and one $2 voucher, getting close to $7 total, but not quite there.

The problem as presented requires multiple iterations over the data set, but with formulas this is not possible to do, AFAIK.

[Click to open the file.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE479525195477F7!7380&authkey=!AFZQvjLTqU0nGco&ithint=file%2Cxlsx) It will open in Excel online and you can download a copy.

Comment: its really nice! im glad you did this ! but if i want to add B4 / C4 formula it always says error:/ if i try to put c4 formula to C4 its not working neither the B4 formula in B4

Comment: You are probably using European settings. You need to replace the commas in the formulas with semicolons. I added a link to the workbook in my post. When you open it it will adjust to your regional settings.

Comment: ou yeah thanks i seee now :) its working ! fantastic ! :)